# jQuery and Canvas loading behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

After being a long time lurker, this is my first post here! I've been RTFMing and searching everywhere for an answer to this question to no avail. I will try to be as informative as I can, hope you could help me.

This code is for my [personal webpage](http://www.nekudator.com.).
I am trying to implement some sort of a modern click-map using HTML5 and jQuery.
In the website you would see the [main image](http://www.nekudator.com/img/main-page.png) and a hidden canvas with the same size at the same coordinates with [this picture](http://www.nekudator.com/img/main-page-buttons.png) drawn into it.

When the mouse hovers the main picture, it read the mouse pixel data (array of r,g,b,alpha) from the image drawn onto the canvas. When it sees the pixel color is black (in my case I only check the RED value, which in a black pixel would be 0) it knows the activate the relevant button.

(Originally, I got the idea from [this article](http://www.rubydesigner.com/blog/click-map-using-html5-canvas))

The reason I chose this method, is for the page to be responsive and dynamically change to fit different monitors and mobile devices. To achieve this, I call the DrawCanvas function every time the screen is re-sized, to redraw the canvas with the new dimensions.

Generally, this works OK. The thing is ,there seems to be an inconsistent behavior in Chrome and IE(9). When I initially open the page, I sometimes get no pixel data (0,0,0,0), until i re-size the browser. At first I figured there's some loading issues that are making this happen so I tried to hack it with setTimeout, it still doesn't work. I also tried to trigger the re-size event and call the drawCanvas function at document.ready, still didn't work.

What's bothering me is most, are the inconsistencies. Sometimes it works, sometimes is doesn't. Generally, it is more stable in chrome than in IE(9).

Here is the deprecated code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){setTimeout(function() {

        // Get main image object    
        var mapWrapper = document.getElementById('map_wrapper').getElementsByTagName('img').item(0);

        // Create a hidden canvas the same size as the main image and append it to main div
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.height = mapWrapper.clientHeight;
        canvas.width = mapWrapper.clientWidth;
        canvas.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
        canvas.style.display = 'none';
        canvas.id = 'hiddencvs';
        $('#map_wrapper').append(canvas);

        // Draw the buttons image into the canvas
        drawCanvas(null);

        $("#map_wrapper").mousemove(function(e){

            var canvas = document.getElementById('hiddencvs');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var pos = findPos(this);
            var x = e.pageX - pos.x;
            var y = e.pageY - pos.y;

            // Get pixel information array (red, green, blue, alpha)
            var pixel = context.getImageData(x,y,1,1).data; 

            var red = pixel[0];
            var main_img = document.getElementById('map_wrapper').getElementsByTagName('img').item(0);

            if (red == 0)
            {
                ...
            }

            else {
                ...
            }   
        });     

    },3000);}); // End DOM Ready

    function drawCanvas(e)
    {
        // Get context of hidden convas and set size according to main image            
        var cvs = document.getElementById('hiddencvs');
        var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
        var mapWrapper = document.getElementById('map_wrapper').getElementsByTagName('img').item(0);
        cvs.width = mapWrapper.clientWidth;
        cvs.height = mapWrapper.clientHeight;


        // Create img element for buttons image
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "img/main-page-buttons.png";

        // Draw buttons image inside hidden canvas, strech it to canvas size    
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,cvs.width,cvs.height);
    }

    $(window).resize(function(e){
            drawCanvas(e);  
        }
    );

    function findPos(obj)
    {
        ...
    }

</script>
```

I'd appreciate any help! 
Thanks!

Ron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't wait for the image to be loaded so, depending on the cache, you may draw an image or not in the canvas.

You should do this :

```
$(function(){
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.onload = function() {
        var mapWrapper = document.getElementById('map_wrapper').getElementsByTagName('img').item(0);
        ...
        // your whole code here !
        ...
    }
    img.src = "img/main-page-buttons.png";
});
```

Comment: Didn't think I'd get an answer in 32 seconds :) It's working now! But when I take out the setTimeout for document.ready it doesn't. Anything else I need to wait to finish loading?

Comment: I don't see what resource you may be missing but try to replace `$(function(){` with `$(window).load(function(){`.

Comment: Great, that did the trick. Many thanks!! (btw, this was not intended to be a marketing post, but you're welcomed to hear my music at youtube.com/ronministube)